# why the selected text not appear?

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon, xul, add-on

hi i have problem with my first addons..
i try to select the word on the website page with this function

```
function getSelected() {
   var userSelection;
   if (window.getSelection) {
      userSelection = window.getSelection();
   } else if (document.selection) {
       userSelection = document.selection.createRange();
   }
   return userSelection;
}

function getText() {
 var select = getSelected()+ "";
  alert(select);
}
```

in my xul i execute the function above with this way :

```
    <menuitem id="inlinetransContextMenuPage"
     label="Terjemahkan dengan inlinetrans"
     onclick="overlay.getText()" />
</popup>
```

but why i the word cannot appear when i select word on page (the pop up is blank)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.getSelection()` returns the selection from the chrome window, which is nearly always empty. As you discovered, you need to use `document.commandDispatcher.focusedWindow` to find out which window has the active selection. (If you're lazy you might have tried `content.getSelection()` but that only works if the page has no frames.)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly what is happening is that by the time the `click` event fires on the XUL `<menuitem>`, the action of clicking it has destroyed the selection in the page. Try using the `mousedown` event instead (i.e. change `onclick` to `onmousedown`).

Also, the `getSelected()` function is needlessly complex. Since your code only needs to work in Firefox, you can use:

```
function getSelected() {
    return window.getSelection().toString();
}
```

Comment: @ Tim Down : it still not work,when i use window.getSelection().toString(); but when i try using document.commandDispatcher.focusedWindow.getSelection().toString(); and it work. why the selected word can't appear with the first way and can appear with the second way..??

Comment: @user495688 are you really working with a single window? The code `window == document.commandDispatcher.focusedWindow` prints true or false?

Comment: @user495688: Sorry, I'm not an expert on Mozilla add-ons. Once you've got hold of the page's `window` object, I'm in business, but as to how you get hold of it in an add-on, I dunno. If `document.commandDispatcher.focusedWindow` works, then perhaps you should use it...